# getting ERROR C4013 - __readcr() undefined; assuming extern returning int

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I'm trying to compile a driver and I'm getting these error:

```
Error   C2220   warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
Error   C4013   '__writecr0' undefined; assuming extern returning int
Error   C4013   '__readcr0' undefined; assuming extern returning int
```

I've included intrin.h too, solution platform is ARM64

```
UINT64 cr0 = __readcr0();
__writecr0( cr0 & 
*(PUSHORT)place = 
*(PULONG)(place + 2) = 
*(PVOID**)(place + 6) = 
__writecr0( cr0 );
```

Comment: @Werner Henze This is not an undefined external symbol, but a missing declaration - the intrinsics header likely has ifdef's only exposing the function for x86 and x86-64 build targets

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/readcr0?view=vs-2017) state that the intrinsic is only available for x86 and x86-64, and even there only in kernel mode. It will thus not work for ARM64 cross compilation.